# Using jruby-openssl in Mule Studio

Tags: ruby, openssl, jruby, mule, jsr223

I need to use openssl in Ruby in Mule Studio. Mule Studio comes pre-packaged with JRuby. As I'm sure you know, JRuby doesn't include openssl. I downloaded the jruby-openssl gem and included the files in my Mule project. I can require the files, all except for jopenssl.jar. Actually I *can* require it, but it doesn't seem to do anything. I see the following error:

```
uninitialized constant OpenSSL::Digest::OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER
```

This is of course referring to the `OpenSSL::OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER`.

Just for fun I manually defined it, but then it kept finding more and more uninitialized constants. I've read some articles saying that the only way to use jruby-openssl is to unzip and combine jruby-complete.jar and jopenssl.jar. Since Mule is using its own copy of JRuby, that's not feasible, not to mention a ridiculous kludge.

So please, does anyone know how to use jruby-openssl in Mule Studio? (FYI I am new to both Mule and JRuby, but am quickly learning to dislike both.)

**Addendum**

A bit of background: We need to transport files over FTPS with Mule. Since it's not directly supported, and we have an existing Ruby implementation, we decided to simply move the Ruby code into Mule. But it requires openssl, which is where this problem began. The `require 'openssl'` line above is what triggers the error.

Here is the relevant Mule/Ruby code:

```
<scripting:transformer name="SetData" doc:name="Set Data">
    <scripting:script engine="jruby">
        <scripting:text><![CDATA[
          require 'socket'
          require 'openssl'
          require 'net/ftp'
          require 'implicit_ftps'
          ...
        ]]></scripting:text>
    </scripting:script>
</scripting:transformer>
```

At your suggestion, I rebuilt the Mule Environment Library, substituting a new JRuby version which includes jopenssl.jar. However I now receive the following error when running my app. As far as I know, except for jruby-complete.jar, nothing else has changed.

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/consolo/bin/MuleStudio/plugins/org.mule.tooling.server.3.2.1_1.0.0.201201200937/mule/boot/mule-module-logging-3.2.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/consolo/bin/MuleStudio/plugins/org.mule.tooling.server.3.2.1_1.0.0.201201200937/mule/boot/mule-module-logging-3.2.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
```

**Update**

Sadly after days of wasted effort, my company has decided that supporting FTPS via Mule is not worth it.

Comment: I'd like to go beyond my answer below and help you investigate the issue. Could please share enough Mule config / Ruby code to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Thanks. I've added more info to the initial question. Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Is it possible that mule-module-logging-3.2.1.jar is added twice on the project build path? Besides the SLF4J warning, is the JRuby code working now?

Comment: I only see 1. If I remove it, the error changes to `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory` and it dies.

Comment: Below the SLF4J warning, I just noticed an exception: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory at at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.createBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:194)` ... `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.<clinit>(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:104)`. So I cannot test the Ruby code yet.

Comment: Mmmh, some JARs present in the original Mule Runtime library seem to be missing. Alas, you would need to compare what you have and the original one to find exactly what. On my side, I took a plain Mule 3.2.1 CE and added jruby-complete v1.6.7.1 in it and I can almost run your code. I have to comment out *require 'implicit_ftps'* otherwise it fails.

Comment: Hmmm, thanks for confirming it works for you. I thought I carefully compared them, but I guess not...

Comment: mule-module-logging-3.2.1.jar is needed, keep it. Could you somewhat share your Studio project with me? Also, don't focus too much on Studio: your target deploy environment is Mule: I'd focus on making the app run on Mule first, then wrestle Studio into submission if needed.

Comment: I needed to uncheck `System Library` on my user library. The app now starts, but I'm still getting the same uninitialized constant Ruby error.

Comment: Strange. What version of jruby-complete.jar do you use? Have you also tried a plain old Mule deploy?

Answer (score 1):

Scripting language support in Mule is pluggable and achieved via JSR-223-compliant providers. Mule CE only embeds Groovy, ie you will have to [add JRuby](http://kenai.com/projects/jruby/pages/JavaIntegration#Java_6_%28using_JSR_223%3a_Scripting%29) to Mule, which will give you the opportunity to pick whatever JAR(s) are needed to achieve your goal.

On the other hand, Mule Studio embeds extra scripting providers, including JRuby. This is convenient but may create issues if a specific version is needed (which seems to be your case).

In Studio, if you open the Mule Runtime library, you'll find *jruby-engine-1.1-jdk14.jar* and *jruby-complete-1.0.jar*. Unfortunately Studio doesn't allow modifying this library, so your best option would be to create a new one, picking all the JARs under `/plugins/org.mule.tooling.server.3.2.1_1.0.0.201201200937/mule` except the jRuby ones (in `./user`) and then add the ones you really need.